# How to make an item non-clickable(item will be visible) in KendoDropDownList

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

```
var items = [ { Id: 0, Title: "Manager" }, { Id: 1, Title: "Developer" }, { Id: 2, Title:      "Vice President" } ];

$("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList({
dataSource: items,
dataTextField: "Title",
dataValueField: "Id"
});
```

Now i Want 0th item("Manager") non clickable.This item will be visible though.

Any Help?

Answer (score 0):

```
#dropdownlist :first-child{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

_

```
element.onclick = function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This is n CSS. I want in JQuery/javascript